# google app engine remote api for local dev server redirecting to login page

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, appcfg

I get a 302 redirection error when trying to use appcfg.py to upload data to my local dev server. If I use a browser to access the relevant page (_ah/remote_api) I get a login page, the pre-filled in test@example.com works, but I get no prompt for that from the cmd line.

Im using the Java variant of GAE, and I've used the upload_data command of appcfg.py before, I think the difference here is that I'm using a newer version than I have before (new machine).

Any thoughts on how to fix this? I have checked around the net, and I cant find anyone else with the issue of being redirected to a login page. The command I am using is:

```
./gae/appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=file
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your xmls? there might be a "login required" somewhere that could be taken off? Normally if you don't force a login you won't get redirected to this page

Comment: @Julldar do you mean web.xml or appengine-web.xml?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I actually meant your web.xml.... but yeah, you seem to have found your issue in the end :P

Answer (score 1):

*sigh*

replacing 127.0.0.1 with localhost works as per the December 19 message here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2440